# Property to reference other properties in the same class c#

Tags: c#

I have a class like this in a legacy system

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string Pro1 { get; set; }
    public string Pro2 { get; set; }
    public string Pro3 { get; set; }
    public string Pro4 { get; set; }
    public string Pro5 { get; set; }
    public string Pro6 { get; set; }
    public string Pro7 { get; set; }
    public string Pro8 { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately the Properties Pro1...Pro8 has been used everywhere in the application. To facilitate access, the developer opted to use reflection to loop through using property names.

```
typeof(MyObj).GetProperty($"Pro{index}");
```

This is really troublesome.

I would like to create a **ordered list** somehow to get rid of the reflection. Something like this

```
public List<string> PropertiesAsList()
{
    Pro1,Pro2,Pro3,Pro4...
}
```

Which later I can do

```
PropertiesAsList[0] = "This should set to Pro1";
```

I **can not** alter or remove the propeties Pro1..Pro4 to list as they are required by other parts in the system. I am only trying a way to access them easily without reflection

I already know that I can create a function

```
SetPropertyByIndex(int index, string value)
{
//huge switch-case?
}
```

Is there a good/better way I can achieve what I want?

Comment: Why/how is the reflection "troublesome"?

Comment: Why can you not "alter" the properties? Surely you can just change them to be backed a list instead?

Comment: The properties is used everywhere without we knowing exactly where. (The IDE wouldn't help since it's reflection based access)
There is also one instance when a developer tried to access "Pro99" which does not exists

Comment: I would be interested in letting the properties be backed by a list. I thought of that but weren't sure how to do that. By "altering" I mean that I can not remove the properties 's getter/setter since they are used everywhere. Would be great if they can be backed by a list "another door to access those properties" that is exactly what I wanted @Sweeper

Comment: How does using a list solve the problem of "the properties is used everywhere without we knowing exactly where"? You still don't won't know where a specific property is used, right? And you will still have people trying to access "Pro99".

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you use properties over fields in the first place. You can now change the implementation of the properties without changing the interface and thus without affecting the code that uses those properties. Simply create a list internally and then implement the getter and setter of each property to get or set the appropriate item of that list.

Comment: @Sweeper I mean it is the downsize of Reflection that we are trying to get rid of "soon". ( That is your original question right? ) 
1 - We are switching all the reflections to the backing list - part by part (hence this question)
2 - Once everything is done we will remove all the Pro1..Pro8 direct access and rely on the List/Ienumerable/Dictionary instead

Comment: By the way: you can also use indexers, so MyObj itself behaves like an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good thing these are properties! You can change the implementations of the getters and setters so that they are backed by a list instead.

```
public class MyObj
{
    private string[] pros = new [] {
        ...
    };

    public string GetPro(int index) => pros[index + 1];
    public void SetPro(int index, string newValue) => pros[index + 1] = newValue;

    public string Pro1 { 
        get => pros[0];
        set => pros[0] = value; 
    }
    public string Pro2 { 
        get => pros[1];
        set => pros[1] = value; 
    }

    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: I would probably use an indexer here: public string this[int n]  {get=>pros[n];set=>pros[n]=value}; also, I'd make the backing field an array because it will never change size.

Comment: @realbart Yeah, array is definitely a better idea in that regard. I chose a list simply because that's what the OP mentioned in the question. Whether an indexer makes sense might depend on what the class actually represents though.

Answer (score 3):

I'll use a simplified example. Change this:

```cs
public class MyObj
{
    public string Pro1 { get; set; }
    public string Pro2 { get; set; }
}
```

to this:

```cs
public class MyObj
{
    public string[] Properties { get; } = new string[] { null, null };
    public string Pro1
    {
        get { return Properties[0]; }
        set { Properties[0] = value;; }
    }
    public string Pro2
    {
        get { return Properties[1]; }
        set { Properties[1] = value; }
    }
}
```

I've used an array so that the length cannot be changed. The existing properties will continue to look and act the same way as before from the outside but you now also have the `Properties` property that you can get and then index to get or set a value in the same array that is now backing the old properties.

Comment: This is the best answer. I'd also consider using an indexer, depending on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the getter:

```
class Foo
{
    public string P1 {get; set;}
    public string P2 {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> Ps
    {
        get
        {
            yield return P1;
            yield return P2;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can

```
var foo = new Foo {
    P1 = "one",
    P2 = "two"
};
foreach (var p in foo.Ps)
{
    Console.Write(p);
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. It'd be good to actually use the OP's object.

Answer (score 0):

You were so close:

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string Pro1 { get; set; }
    public string Pro2 { get; set; }
    public string Pro3 { get; set; }
    public string Pro4 { get; set; }
    public string Pro5 { get; set; }
    public string Pro6 { get; set; }
    public string Pro7 { get; set; }
    public string Pro8 { get; set; }

    public List<string> PropertiesAsList() => new List<string>()
    {
        Pro1, Pro2, Pro3, Pro4, Pro5, Pro6, Pro7, Pro8,
    };

    public string this[int index] => PropertiesAsList()[index - 1];
}
```

Now you can write this:

```
var myObj = new MyObj() { Pro4 = "Hello" };
Console.WriteLine(myObj[4]);
```

It would write out "Hello".

Comment: As far as I can tell (and I might be misreading this), OP wants to be able to simply write `PropertiesAsList[0] = "This should set to Pro1";`, without having to have a special method just to update the property too. But, as I said, I might be misreading/misunderstanding.

Comment: If this way you edit PropertiesAsList[n], the changes aren't applied to the MyObj because a copy was made

Comment: If the pros are actually numbered I'd consider renaming pro8 to pro0 so you can align withh a zero based array.